# Python PIL NameError global name Image is not defined

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, python-requests

I installed PIL 1.1.7 using the executable for Python 2.7. But when I run this code :

```
import requests
from PIL import *

def main() :
    target = "http://target/image.php" #returns binary data for a PNG.
    cookies = {"mycookie1", "mycookie2"}
    r = requests.get(target, cookies=cookies)
    im = Image.open(r.content) #r.content contains binary data for the PNG.
    print im

if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

It gives the error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Programming\Python\code\eg_cc1.py", line 17, in <module>
  main()
File "D:\Programming\Python\code\eg_cc1.py", line 13, in main
  im = Image.open(r.content)
NameError: global name 'Image' is not defined
```

I installed PIL in `Lib\site-packages`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to explicitly import the Image module:

```
>>> from PIL import *
>>> Image
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'Image' is not defined
>>> import PIL.Image
>>> Image
<module 'Image' from 'c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.pyc'>
>>>
```

Or just

```
>>> import Image
```

Answer (score 13):

Use

```
from PIL import Image
```

This way it will work, and your code will be forward-compatible with [**Pillow**](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). On the other hand, `import Image` [will *not* work with Pillow](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/porting-pil-to-pillow.html).

The development of PIL has been stopped in mid 2011, without any official announcement or explication. Pillow is a fork of original PIL and is actively developed.

Comment: (Commenting in 2017 here) thank you, this is the only way it worked.

Comment: global name 'PIL' is not defined

Answer (score 5):

If

```
import Image
```

is not working.
Try:

```
from PIL import Image
```

There is compatibility issue with all the packages in **PIL**. Try downloading PIL package manually for the latest version.
Actually worked with this in **Python 3.2 Version**, everything is working fine.